# Can anybody explain what this code exactly do?

Tags: php, security

I found this code in my project index.php file and I am sure that I have never added this code, I am bit worried, Can you guy's please explain what this piece of code do exactly?

```
if (preg_match('/\/admin\/Cms_Wysiwyg\/directive\/index\//', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if (isset($_REQUEST['___directive']) && isset($_REQUEST['forwarded'])) {
            if (preg_match('/report_search_grid/', base64_decode($_REQUEST['___directive'])))
                $_REQUEST['forwarded'] = $_POST['forwarded'] = $_GET['forwarded'] = $_COOKIE['forwarded'] = null;
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: What wrong with this? can anybody add the comments?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install  [Magento security patch](http://magento.com/security-patch)

It is sign of compromised site